# Show Quantity label when product is in cart(Swift 5)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, swift5

When user add the product to cart.The selected product must show the increment and decrement button. and others product should only show the add button.
You can check this image

[image]

The problem is that when I comes back to this screen again it should show the quantity label till The product is in cart.
as I have no property in backend that stores the boolean value that product is in cart or not ?
Can anybody tell the same thing how to do this in frontend ?
so that only items in cart shows the quantity label in product TableView.

Here is my code

Product TableView

```
func getCartDetails()
    {
        ApiCaller().getData(url: get_cart_url, resultType: CartResult.self) { (results) in
            self.iddd = results.result!.id
            self.c = results.result!
            guard let resultArray = results.result?.cartItems as? [CartItem] else {return }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(results.result?.cartItems.count, forKey: "totalItemsInCart")
            
            for cart in resultArray
            {
                
                self.cAr.append(cart)
                
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    }


func addItem(prodId:String,qty:Int,cartId:String)
    {
 
        let request = cartProducts(products: [addCartProducts(prodId:prodId, q: qty + 1)])
        
        do
        {
            let encodedResult = try JSONEncoder().encode(request)
            
            ApiCaller().postData(url: update_cart_url+cartId+"/update", requestBody: encodedResult, requestMethod: "PUT", resultType: UpdateCartResults.self) { (results) in
                print(results.statusCode)
              
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                
            }
            
            
        }catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
            
        
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ProductsTVCell
        

        cell.generateCells(products: productArray[indexPath.row])
        
 
        let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: rupee + "\(productArray[indexPath.row].mrpAfterDiscount)")
        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        
        cell.secondPriceLbl.attributedText = attributeString
        
        cell.addBtnLbl.tag = indexPath.row
        
        


let productAtIndex = self.productArray[indexPath.row]

          
        
        if cAr.contains(where: { (item) -> Bool in
            productAtIndex.id == item.id
        }){
            // product is in cart, show increment/decrement button
            
             cell.addBtnLbl.isHidden = true
        } else {
            // product not in cart, show add button
            
             cell.addBtnLbl.isHidden = false
        }
        
        cell.callBackForAddButtonHidden = {
        
            cell.addBtnLbl.isHidden = true
            guard self.c != nil else {
                print("Creating cart for the first time")
                self.createCart(prodId: self.productArray[indexPath.row].id, qty: 1)
                return
                
            }
                self.addItem(prodId: self.productArray[indexPath.row].id, qty: 0, cartId: self.c!.id)
        }
        
    
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        
        return cell
    }
```

Here is my product TableView cell
I tried using comparing cartDetails and productDetails but it did not worked so i commented it that.

```
func generateCells(products:Product)
    {
        self.productNameLbl.text = products.name
        self.productDescriptionLbl.text = products.additionInfo
        self.productPriceLbl.text = rupee + String(products.productMRP)

        if products.discountPercentage != 0
        {
        self.discountLbl.text = "\(products.discountPercentage)% Off"
        } else {
            self.discountLbl.isHidden = true
        }
        //

//        if products.id == cartDetails.id
//        {
//            addBtnLbl.isHidden = true
//            self.quantityLbl.text = "\(cartDetails.qty)"
//        } else {
//            addBtnLbl.isHidden = false
//        }
        
        
        self.productImgView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: products.imgURL)) { (image, error, cache, url) in
            
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your card is an array of `Product`, you can check in your `cellForRowAt indexPath` whether the item at current index is present in your cart and show/hide buttons accordingly.

```
let productAtIndex = self.productArray[indexPath.row]

    if cart.contains(where: { (item) -> Bool in
        productAtIndex.id == item.id
    }){
        // product is in cart, show increment/decrement button
    } else {
        // product not in cart, show add button
    }
```

Comment: This code is working fine but when I try to add new product it shows qunatity for 1 sec then again sets to false

Comment: When you are calling `self.createCart` or `self.addItem`, where is the product id updated? Is it not in `cAr` array?

Comment: It is getting updated but cAr is not getting updated.It will get updated when I will load that view again.And I think this is causing error

Comment: then use that array instead of `cAr` in `cellForRowAt indexPath`

Comment: Do I need to make new arr to store productItem ? as now when user clicks on add button it posts the data and when we load the view again.We fetched the data from Cart api and  append it to cAr

Comment: If you are reloading the tableview after updating `cAr`, there should be no issues, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219684/discussion-between-motivation-gym5-and-jithin).